# Expandable List View in Tabs

Tags: java, android, list, android-tabs

I am a quite new to Java, and I've been stumped making Expandable `ListView` in Tabs following relevant tutorials. Let me explain further. I currently have 2 Tabs and I want to display two separate ELV with different datas. i.e., one for "Recipes" and the other for "Ingredients".

I've been able to make an ELV and display it (with the Recipes data) however, swiping between the two tabs, the ELV with Recipes (my first set of data) is also shown in the Ingredients tab.  Unfortunately, I am unsure how to call or where to call for my Ingredients data to be shown instead of my Recipes data.

I am unsure what other relevant code I need to post but here is where I suspect the problem may lay though unsure what:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
    Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    Recipes_category = RecipesProvider.getInfo();
    Recipes_list = new ArrayList<String>(Recipes_category.keySet());
    adapter = new RecipesAdapter(this, Recipes_category, Recipes_list);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


}
```

I am unfamiliar with the certain Java words so please excuse me if my explanation is not yet precise, I didn't want to confuse anyone by throwing out words I am not quite sure of. Don't hesitate to ask for more information about my code :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a default option in Android studio that will allow you to use fragments, which is what I suggest that you use.

Here is the API:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

The idea is that you create two different XML files that act as seperate views that you can tab between.